# refactor code to throw RuntimeException instead of return a value

Tags: java, refactoring, runtimeexception

I need to refactor an existing code because of code duplication.

The following structure occures more then 10 times in a crazy class:

```
public MyType doSomething(...) {
    MyType myType = ........
    if (myType == null) {
        final String message = "...";
        LOGGER.error(message);
        throw new XxxRuntimeException(message));
    }
    return myType;
}
```

I would like to refactor `LOGGER.error` and `throw new RuntimeException` lines to a new method like this:

```
private void logErrorAndThrowRuntimeException(String message) {
    LOGGER.error(message);
    throw new XxxRuntimeException(message));
}
```

The problem with this is there is no return value inside the `if` contition after refactor.

I an not able to change the type of the exception from `RuntimeException` to `Exception` because this application has a crazy logic and RuntimeExceptin needs to be thrown.

Any idea how to refactor this two lines of code to a new method and keep the logic of the original method untouched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a Throwable return type:

```
private XxxRuntimeException logErrorAndThrowRuntimeException(String message) {
    LOGGER.error(message);
    // You can throw here, or return if you'd prefer.
    throw new XxxRuntimeException(message));
}
```

Then you can throw this at the call site to indicate that the if body cannot complete normally:

```
public MyType doSomething(...) {
    MyType myType = ........
    if (myType == null) {
        final String message = "...";
        throw logErrorAndThrowRuntimeException(message);
    }
    return myType;
}
```